# How to safely use user input in file path

Tags: php

As I show it, I expect `file_get_contents(file);` is a bad idea and `require($file);` is worse.

How can I ensure that `$file` cannot be modified by the user other than as intended (by "intended", I mean no `..` or anything which would change the path)?

```
$file=dirname(__DIR__).'/components/'.$_GET['cid'].'/validate/'.$_GET['page'].'.json';
$json=file_get_contents(file);
require($file);
```

Comment: Whitelist the allowed values. Or at least constrain them (regexp, basename, etc).

Comment: Why would you want to do this in the first place? And what are the requirements? What things CAN a user type?

Comment: @putvande  It is an ajax request which will respond with content from a file.  Obviously, someone doesn't need to use my JavaScript, and could generate their own malicious request.

Comment: @mario  In a sense, I am white listing them as if the file doesn't exist, I could respond appropriately (didn't show this part).  My thought is if the strings contain only alphanumerical and are not empty, I should be good, but wish to make sure.

Comment: Take a look at phps function to translate a given path into the "real local path". Then test the result against a whiltelist. That is the only reliable and secure approach. Forget regexes. http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php

Comment: @arkascha  I've never used this function, but it is exactly what I was hoping for!  Let me check it out.  Thanks

Comment: But still it is _very_ questionable if what you try is a good idea. One of the basics of web programming is that the client must not be given knowledge about the internal details of the server. Why would you want to expose your internal file system hierarchy? There is no use for such thing! If you really want to publish files in a local folder (like web technology from the 80th), then do that via a "router" script that can check authorization and validate the user input and then decide to send the file or not. But use logical paths, not physical ones.

Comment: @arkascha  They won't see the path.  They will see something like `$.getJSON( 'index.php',{cid:'users',page:'edit',task:'getValidationJSON',id:$('#id').val()}, function(validateJSON) {});`.  PHP will then intiate `getValidationJSON()` which in turn will use $_GET to obtain the correct file.

Comment: WHAT? lets put aside that this does not match what you say in your question. But do you really want to say that you want to have the client decide what function is executed on the server side? Really? _Why?_

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86518/discussion-between-user1032531-and-arkascha).